# Threading socket server in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm working on a threading server in Python but I'm running into problems with one connection blocking.  When I make the first connection, it sleeps and then I don't get anything back on the second connection to the server until the first is done sleeping.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import socket, ssl, time, threading

def test_handler(conn):
    print "sleeping 10 seconds"
    time.sleep(10)
    conn.write("done sleeping")
    return 0


class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connstream):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = connstream        

    def run(self):
        test_handler(self.conn)


threads = []
bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 10023))
bindsocket.listen(10)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                 server_side=True,
                                 certfile="server.crt",
                                 keyfile="server.key",
                                 ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    try:
        c = ClientThread(connstream)
        c.start()
        threads.append(c)
    finally:
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
```

Answer (score 4):

It blocks because you're `join`ing your new thread (and all the others) after each new connection is established. [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) blocks until the thread terminates, so only call it when you actually want to wait until the thread is done.

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome. I swear I didn't get an email on this before.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Steve Trout's insight -- here is the modified code.  It starts a thread when a client connects, but doesn't `join` until the end of the server.  It also has more extensive logging.

### source

```
import logging, socket, ssl, sys, time, threading

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)-4s %(threadName)s %(message)s", 
    datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
    stream=sys.stderr,
)

def test_handler(conn):
    logging.info("sleeping 1 second")
    time.sleep(1)
    conn.send("done sleeping\n")
    return 0


class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connstream):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = connstream        

    def run(self):
        test_handler(self.conn)

def main():
    port = 10023
    bindsocket = socket.socket()
    bindsocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
    bindsocket.listen(10)

    logging.info('listening on port %d', port)
    while True:
        newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
        logging.info('connect from %s', fromaddr)
        connstream = newsocket
        if 0:
            connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(
                newsocket,
                server_side=True,
                certfile="server.crt",
                keyfile="server.key",
                ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
        ClientThread(connstream).start()

    logging.info('stop')

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

    # make sure all threads are done
    for th in threading.enumerate():
        if th != threading.current_thread():
            th.join()
```

Comment: Thanks - I had no idea about join blocking on threads.  This code looks much cleaner than what I had.